# Sql :Subtraction formula for different Columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

Im trying to write a formula in `SQL Server` to subtract the values of two columns which are `[AmountSpent]`column of table2 and `[Amount]` column of table1of two different tables and update the balance amount in [Amount] column any idea ?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: A *general* recommendation for relational databases is that you don't store the result of computations - unless there are specific performance reasons for doing so. A stored calculation always has the potential to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work, assuming you have a reliable foreign key relationship between the two tables

```
UPDATE [table1]
SET [table1].[Amount] = [table1].[Amount] - [table2].[AmountSpent]
FROM
[table1] INNER JOIN
[table2] ON
[table1].[KeyField] = [table2].[KeyField]
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it.........thanks @james Osborn

```
     create procedure SP_Subtraction
      (
       @EmpID int 
       )
      as
      begin
      UPDATE PTS_BalanceTracker
      SET PTS_BalanceTracker.Balance_BalanceAmount = PTS_BalanceTracker.Balance_BalanceAmount - PTS_Transactions.Transaction_Amount
      FROM
      PTS_BalanceTracker INNER JOIN
      PTS_Transactions ON
      PTS_BalanceTracker.Emp_ID = @EmpID
      end
```